# More than one commandline input in perl using argV

Tags: perl, command-line, command-line-arguments, perl-module

How to use command line argument in Perl to take input a file from user? May be like: `wxp.pl - file {file path}`.
I am new one in Perl so suggest me anything which is helpful. And how can I make it like more then one arguments to ask in command line.
ex:

```
exp.pl -file {file path}
           -x    {it's arg}
           -y    {y's arg}
```

Answer (score 2):

If simple you want pass arguments, you can do like this:

```
perl exp.pl arg1 agr2
```

If you want something more, use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) module.

Comment: Ohhk thank you i have to look that up  **Getopt::Long** because i have no idea how to do that New into the perl you know.

Comment: Just have a look and try to do from yourself, and if you face any problem come here with your attempts. We glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest GetOpt::Long to achieve that. But if you want to make your own see if something like this would be handy:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Usage check. For "perl xxx.pl -a arg1 -b arg2" args. should be even nos. 

if (scalar @ARGV == 0 or scalar @ARGV % 2 != 0) {
    print "Usage:\n\t$0 -a arg1 -b arg2 requires all args\n";
    exit 0;
}

# This one convert cmd line args. to hash ex. (perl xxx.pl -a arg1 -b arg2) to {-a => arg1, -b => arg2}
my %argHash = @ARGV;    

# Optional but see if all the args are present
my $maxArgs = 2;
if (scalar keys %argHash != $maxArgs) {
    print "Usage:\n\t$0 -a arg1 -b arg2 requires exactly $maxArgs args\n";
    exit 0;
}

# Parse arguments. 
print "$0:\n";
for my $key (keys %argHash) {
    print "\t $key: $argHash{$key}\n";  
}

1;
```

Result:

```
c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl
Usage:
        cmdline.pl -a arg1 -b arg2 requires all args

c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl -a "user" -b
Usage:
        cmdline.pl -a arg1 -b arg2 requires all args

c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl -a "user" -b "Command"
cmdline.pl:
         -a: user
         -b: Command

c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl -a "user" -b "Command" -c "mock"
Usage:
        cmdline.pl -a arg1 -b arg2 requires exactly 2 args

c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl -a "user"
Usage:
        cmdline.pl -a arg1 -b arg2 requires exactly 2 args
```

Answer (score 1):

More simpler GetOpt::Long version

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my $user_name;

GetOptions('user=s' => \$user_name) or die "Usage: $0 --user NAME\n";

if ($user_name) {
    print  $user_name, "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl -user Swadhi
Swadhi

c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl

c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl -p s
Unknown option: p
Usage: cmdline.pl --user NAME

c:\swadhi\perl>perl cmdline.pl -u "This should also work"
This should also work
```

Comment: well i will try to use this one in my solution and thanks.Though i am working on a email module in which i want to enter a email ids as an argument so with that it will send a mail to those id and i am using mail::outlook for that.

Comment: Sure. I would recommend that you practice it for fuller understanding and left it out with very simple example. Cheer! :)